# Adding a submenu to menu

Tags: java, netbeans

I am having trouble getting my submenu to show up when I select input 3)Select Students in my main menu.
Any help fixing this is greatly appreciated, Thank you!

here is the main menu (shows up first when I run the code)

```
 public void menu() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input;
    do {
        System.out.println("1) Populate Students");
        System.out.println("2) Load Students from file");
        System.out.println("3) Select Students");
        System.out.println("4) Show Students");
        System.out.println("5) Save Students to file");
        System.out.println("6) Exit");
        input = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
        if (input == 1) 
        {
            populateStudents();
        } else if (input == 2) {
            loadStudents();
        } else if (input == 3) {
            selectStudents();
        } else if (input == 4) {
            showStudents();
        } else if (input == 5) {
            saveStudents();
        }
    } while (input != 6);

}
```

This is my sub menu code, I want to be able to select input 3 from the main menu and call this sub menu to then select from.

```
    public void studentSubMenu(int i) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    { 
        System.out.println("Student Menu, select an option");
   int input = 0;
 
   while(input != 5)
   {
            System.out.println("1) Calculate Average");
            System.out.println("2) Calculate Weighted Average");
            System.out.println("3) Determine Letter Grade");
            System.out.println("4) Display Students info");
            System.out.println("5) GO BACK");
          Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
          input=sc.nextInt();
        
            if (input == 1) 
            {
               myStudents[i].calcAvg();
            } 
            if (input == 2) 
            {
                 myStudents[i].calcAvg(.7, .3);
            } 
            if (input == 3) 
            {
                myStudents[i].calcLetterGrade();
            } 
            if (input == 4) 
            {
                 myStudents[i].displayStudent();
            } else if (input == 5) {
                menu();
            }
             
         }
```

Comment: Your case for a user entering `3` on the main menu calls a method called `selectStudents` - while your sub menu is in another method called `studentSubMenu`. You aren't actually invoking `studentSubMenu` anywhere in your menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment:

The issue here is that the case you have written for handling the input of `3` in the `menu` method calls another method called `selectStudents`.

This is not the method containing your sub menu logic. That method you have named `studentSubMenu`. This means that if the desired behavior of a user entering `3` is them being shown the sub menu, this won't occur unless `studentSubMenu` is either called directly in the `else if (input == 3)` block, or by `selectStudents` itself.

Your logic in `menu` could look something like:

```
} else if (input == 3) {
    int student = selectStudents();
    studentSubMenu(student);
}
```